# Issue with WORDPRESS MULTISITE

Tags: multisite

Step by step Im fallow to guide:
https://multilingualpress.org/docs/how-to-install-wordpress-multisite/

I have crated additional website:
[image]

Main website working. Only issue with this new both.

Also I add DNS A record to DirectAdmin and CloudFlare etc.

after run  our new site with subdomain example
de.mymynewsite.com  I get issue:
Apache is functioning normally

propagation had to take place. So can anyone give a hint?

Comment: What is the issue you're having. Can you please share the error message?

Comment: you can check it: pl.csdroppy.com or de.csdroppy.com

Answer (score 1):

The "Apache is functioning normally" page is a default page. In this situation, it is indicating your Apache configuration needs to be updated to direct the  `pl.csdroppy.com` or `de.csdroppy.com` hosts to the directory containing the WordPress codebase.

The [Domain-based section of the Before You Create A Network docs page](https://wordpress.org/support/article/before-you-create-a-network/#domain-based) describes three ways of configuring Apache for subdomain-based multisite networks

- by configuring wildcard subdomains
- by configuring virtual hosts, specifying the same document root for each
- by creating addon domains or subdomains in cPanel or in a similar web hosting control panel

The [Configuring Wildcard Subdomains](https://wordpress.org/support/article/configuring-wildcard-subdomains/) docs go on to suggest using the `Server Alias` directive in your `VirtualHost`. In your case, this would be:

```
ServerAlias *.csdroppy.com
```